# Visual Studio IntelliSense with Class Created During Python Runtime

Tags: python, visual-studio, intellisense

I am working on creating a class that is created at runtime. During runtime, it grabs all functions from each file that it shares a directory with, and adds them to the class. Example folder below:

```
Folder
    ClassCreatedAtRuntime.py
    module_with_various_functions.py
    another_module_with_different_functions.py
```

The 'ClassCreatedAtRuntime' class will grab all functions within each module in the same folder and create a class at runtime that has each of those functions.

Because the class is created at runtime, IntelliSense cannot know what functions the class has available, and does not autocomplete. I want to be able to use IntelliSense with this runtime class. Is there a way to implement this? Perhaps a Visual Studio extension? Or is this out of the question?

I'm using Python 2.7 if that matters.

Thanks!

**Edit: Looks like the answer is no for Visual Studio for now. I have submitted a feature request. Does anyone know if this is possible in another IDE, like PyCharm?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to use IntelliSense with this runtime class. Is
>   there a way to implement this? Perhaps a Visual Studio extension? Or
>   is this out of the question?

**I am afraid that you cannot get what you want so far.**

**For** a python class created at run time, it is already controlled by the created process and occupied by multiple worker processes, so simultaneous intellisense cannot capture it.

**And** I have searched for a long time and there is no such extension to realize it.

**So** to get what you want, you can suggest a feature request on [our User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(Suggest a Feature) to reflect your requirements and I think the staff will consider it carefully and get a satisfactory reply.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer was very helpful. I have submitted a feature request at the link you provided. Hopefully it will be looked at and considered. Thanks!

Edit: Is there a way to do it in another program, such as PyCharm?